# laravel use $app inside routes error Undefined variable: app

Tags: laravel, routes

laravel 5.2 documentation has used `$app->get(..)` in [routing section](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing). i cant use `$app` inside routes , it throw below exception:

```
ErrorException in routes.php line 15:

Undefined variable: app
```

Comment: use this  Route::get('admin/password', 'Admin\SettingsController@change_password'); insted of $app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such global variable as `$app` in Laravel. You are probably referring to Lumen.

Laravel framework at www.laravel.com is different from Lumen framework at www.lumen.laravel.com

Lumen is 'slim down' version of Laravel

If you are trying to register a route in Laravel this will do.

```
Route::get('/', function () { return 'Hello World'; });
```

Want to use variable?Try

```
$router->get('/', function () { return 'Hello World'; });
```

If you are interested in accessing app, which is not used for routing, try

```
 $app = app();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you've linked to is for `Lumen`, not `Laravel`. Lumen is different than Laravel, and actually uses a completely different router than Laravel, so the routing is setup a little differently.

Routing in Laravel uses the `Route` facade. For example:

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

You want to take a look at the [Laravel Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing).