# Undefined variable $app in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to build laravel application on ver 5.3, I'm creating a service provider and trying to register following:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->checkDomainName();
    $this->app->singleton('domain', function()
    {
        return $this->domain;
    });
}

/**
 * Checking domain status
 */
public function checkDomainName()
{
    $domain = php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? 'nitseditor.com' : $this->app['request']->server('HTTP_HOST');
    return $domain;
}
```

Now I'm calling die dump app variable through a controller:

```
namespace Nitseditor\Controller;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use \App;

class DomainController extends Controller
{
    //

    function index()
    {
        dd($app);
    }
}
```

I mean I'm checking wether it has been associated to app like `$app['domain']` or not. But it is showing undefined variable app. Help me out.

Comment: Are you referring to Laravel or Lumen? *There's not **`$app`** global variable in Laravel!*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel use $app inside routes error Undefined variable: app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619101/laravel-use-app-inside-routes-error-undefined-variable-app)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `app()` helper method which return the available container instance, try it as:

```
dd(app());
```

And in your case, your can do it as:

```
app('domain');
```

Comment: Are you not able to use app() method?

Comment: No. I tried using `\App::make('domain');` I'm getting error `ErrorException in DomainServiceProvider.php line 37: 
Undefined property: Nitseditor\Providers\DomainServiceProvider::$domain`

Comment: You can try it as `$this->domain = $this->checkDomainName();` in your register method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `app()` helper instead of variable. But in controller and other Laravel classes it's much more convinient to use [automatic injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#automatic-injection):

```
function index(BindedClass $variable)
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no `$app` variable defined in the scope of your controller's method. If you're trying to access Laravel's IoC container, you can use the `app()` helper function.

```
$app = app();
```

In your case, if you're trying to access the `'domain'` that you bound in your service provider you can pass the string `'domain'` as a parameter to `app()`

```
$domain = app('domain');
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of `Undefined property: Nitseditor\Providers\DomainServiceProvider::$domain`

Comment: That's an error in your service provider, which is a separate issue. It refers to where you've used `$this->domain`. It means that it can't find a property named "domain". Can't help any further until you provide the rest of your code.

Comment: Also, why the downvote? My answer, which is similar to most other answers below is pretty much correct.